# Как можно оправдать использование тире взамен запятой?

Tags: тире

Как можно оправдать использование тире взамен запятой? Ведь нельзя же всегда ставить в конце тире, чтобы обозначить вставочную конструкцию, — значит, нужна другая веская причина.

> Изучать немецкий прям-с по-быстрому-таки начала я — уча грамматику.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно:

*Изучать немецкий прям-с по-быстрому-таки начала я — **уча грамматику.***

**Пояснение**

Обособление деепричастного **оборота** тире связано **с инверсией**, сравнить:

(1) *Изучать немецкий я по-бЫстрому начала , // **уча граммАтику.***

Нормальный порядок слов, достаточно **запятой**.

(2) *Изучать немецкий по-бЫстрому **начала я** — /// **уча грамматику**.*

**Инверсия,** пояснение наречия "по-быстрому" (как именно?) после **предикативной** основы. С помощью тире обозначен **присоединительный** характер деепричастного оборота.

Comment: Это больше пояснительная конструкция на самом деле.

Comment: Да, пояснительная, но оформленная как присоединение, так как инверсированная структура не вписывается в предложение естественным образом. Предикативная основа следует за наречием, которое нужно пояснить.

Comment: Я ничего такого не пишу. Просто пишу и не критикую ответ. Просто немного "дополнил". Это ничего страшного так-то. Может, я и стал похожим на @oleedd, не знаю. Немного времени? Потому что я такой человек, которому быстро что-либо надоедает. Например, телефонные игры. Здесь набирать репутацию мне тоже быстро надоело, нет стремления. Нельзя точно сказать, из-за отношений это наших или нет. Ну и почему же (к части вопроса: «Так как я психолог-любитель, то даже знаю почему») ?

Comment: Ничего такого вы действительно не написали. Замечание даже принесло мне пользу для улучшения ответа. Мой второй комментарий относится к вашей подчеркнутой позиции – комментировать вопросы и ответы, но не отвечать самому.  А ведь в общем случае это запрещено правилами.